# set daily limit of a product magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, product

How I can set a daily order limit for a particular product?

For example if we set the daily limit for a product (test Product) to 5, then the maximum quantity available for the product is 5 on daily basis.

If the product quantity order is reached for a day, then on add to cart a message is shown that the daily limit for product order has reached the maximum level.

Comment: For this you need to create an extension

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default way to achieve this with Magento. You need to create your own extension.

The extension should do:

- Add a field to Magento Admin product detail page where an individual daily limit per product can be set
- Add a check on when product is added to cart if the daily limit has been reached
- *Optional:* A cronjob that restores the daily limit after 24h

Please inform yourself about how to write an extension and show us some code so we can provide help. Without any code we cannot help and I totally agree with @enigmativity.